# comparing branch cuts

Tags: complex-analysis

Comparing branch cuts for $f(z)=\ln_{-{\pi /2}}(4-z^2)$ and $g(z)=\ln_{-{\pi /2}}(2-z) + \ln_{-{\pi /2}}(2+z)$

---

branch points of  $f(z)$ are $2,-2$ but i think in first look $g(z)$ is equal to $f(z)$ but  $\ln(z_1)+ln(z_2) \neq \ln(z_1z_2)$ then  $2$ is a branch point of 1st logarithm and $-2$ is the branch point of 2nd logarithm .now let $2-z=re^{i\theta},2+z=se^{i\phi}$ then $g(z)=ln|r/s|+i(Arg\theta+Arg\phi)-\pi $ then how evaluate the branch cut then how compare it from $f(z)$???

Comment: lol brunch cuts... I feel hungry now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the $\ln_{-\pi/2}$ means you take logarithm by cutting through the half line $\{-iy: 0\leq y \in\mathbb R\}$.

Hence for $f$, you are cutting through all $z$ such that $i(4 - z^2)$ is a non-negative real number. Draw a graph to see what these are.

While for $g$, you are cutting through all $z$ such that $i(2 - z)$ is a non-negative real number, or $i(2 + z)$ is a non-negative real number. Draw a graph to see what these are.

Then compare your two graphs.